# for loops in MIPS

Tags: loops, for-loop, mips

I have problems writing for loops in MIPS: I have the following for loop to write but I cant figure it out. To be honest I don't understand MIPS at all.

How would this be written in MIPS

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brief example of one approach of using "for-loop" in MIPS.
We will use $2 to store i, $1 to store 4, $5 to store 1 and $6 for temporary storage.
Note: everything after # are comments

```
#initialize  
addi $1, $0, 4 #store 4 to $1  
add $2, $0, $0 #set i to 0  
addi $5, $0, 1 #set 1 to $5  

#for loop  
loop:  
slt $6, $2, $1 #check if $2<4 and store result in $6  
beq $6, $5, endloop #if $6 contains a 1, exit loop  

#rest of code in loop  

add $2, $2, $5 #increment i  
beq $0, $0, loop #go back to loop label  

endloop:  

#rest of mips code outside loop
```